# Is it a correct definition of the moduli space $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ of marked curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, moduli-space

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$. Consider the set $$M=\{(X,\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}): x_k\in X \text{ }\&\text{ } x_i\ne x_j\text{ for }i\ne j\}.$$
Define an equivalence relation on $M$ in the following way:
$(X,\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}) \sim (X',\{x_1',\dots,x_n'\}) $ iff there exists a biholomorphic map $f: X\rightarrow X'$ of Riemann surfaces such that $f(x_i)=x_i'$ for every $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$.

Is it correct to say that, by definition, $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}=M/\sim$ ?

Comment: You have fixed the complex structure on $X$. As a trivial example, if $n=0$, then your set $M/\sim$ will have one element (since, in particular, $M$ has one element) but of course if the genus is larger than zero $\mathcal{M}_{g,0}$ is $6g-6$-dimensional.

Comment: @Neal: I see; though I  didn't mean to fix any particular complex structire on $X$, the first sentence indeed seems to imply the converse. Is there a way to correct this definition properly?

Comment: Rather than fix a compact Riemann surface $X$, let $X$ vary over all such objects. What you have described here is the fiber over $X$ of the forgetful map $\mathcal{M}_{g,n} \to \mathcal{M}_g$.

Comment: Even if we fix it up I wouldn't call this a definition, in the sense that there's no universal property or any structure given beyond that of a plain set.